# WebApplicationContext is always null when running Geb integration test

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-boot, geb

Why isn't my context being injected? The application runs fine. Integration tests using Spring's junit runner and MockMvc run fine. Do I need to add something to integrate Spring and Spock?

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyConfiguration)
@WebAppConfiguration
class BetaRequestTest extends GebReportingSpec{

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext; //always null

    def setup() {
        browser.driver = MockMvcHtmlUnitDriverBuilder
                .webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build()
    }

    def destroy(){
        browser.driver?.close()
    }

    @Test
    def void "should render the page"(){
        setup:
            to BetaRequestPage
        expect:
            $('h1').value() == "Welcome to Foo"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

I needed to add the following test dependency:

```
testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.0-groovy-2.4"
```